# How can I use lag function to obtain same day changes in customer movement type

Tags: sql, time, lag

I have a dataset that I am trying to get the total number of times a customer has left during a same day period (basically a refund).

If a customer has a new business and a churn with the same transaction time, then it is considered a refund. i was trying to use the lag function for this, but I am simply getting any result if there is change from new_business to churn. What I need is a change from new_business to churn as well as happening during the same day period.

Data looks like:

```
user_id       time         transaction_type
  1234     2020-01-10          new_business
  1234     2020-01-10              churn
  5678     2020-01-10          new_business 
  5678.    2020-05-01              churn
  1011     2020-01-10          new_business
```

In the above example, user_id 1234 would be a refund but 5678 would not be. user 1011 is still a customer. I am trying to get the total count of refund customers

My query:

`select count(*)
lag(time) over (partition by user_id order by time)
from data
where transaction_type in('churn','new_business')`

However whats happening with this query is that I am getting all times there is a change with both of them. So I am getting user_id 1234 and 5678. What am I missing in order to limit this to only user_id 1234?

Comment: What results do you want?

Answer (score 1):

If you want people who have the two types on the same date, then you can use aggregation:

```
select user_id, time
from data
where transaction_type in ('churn', 'new_business')
group by user_id, time
having count(distinct transaction_type) = 2;
```

If you want a count of these, you can use a subquery.

Comment: This simply gets users who have both, it does not factor in if its happening the same day.

Comment: @user3120266 . . . .`time` should be in the `group by`.